# How do I fade in vertical menu child items using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, superfish

Here is my vertical menu
http://jsfiddle.net/3PD7D/13/

If you hover over the menu items named folders nothing happens however if you go to where the menu items should appear(to the right of the "folder" menu item(s)) the jquery fades in the submenu items. How do I get them to fade in when the user hovers over the parent "folder" menu item?

**Edited**
I apologize for not asking in the proper way. Here is the original code I should have posted. Many thanks to CasperOne and roasted for showing me the error of my ways.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
//Set the anchor link opacity to 0 and begin hover function
$("ul.child").css({"opacity" : 0}).hover(function(){ 

    //Fade to an opacity of 1 at a speed of 200ms
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity" : 1}, 200); 

    //On mouse-off
    }, function(){

    //Fade to an opacity of 0 at a speed of 100ms
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity" : 0}, 100); 

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [there](http://jsfiddle.net/3PD7D/14/) for a working sample.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    //Set the anchor link opacity to 0 and begin hover function
    $("ul.child").parent().hover(function(){ 

        //Fade to an opacity of 1 at a speed of 200ms
        $(this).find("ul.child").stop().animate({"opacity" : 1}, 200); 

        //On mouse-off
        }, function(){

        //Fade to an opacity of 0 at a speed of 100ms
        $(this).find("ul.child").stop().animate({"opacity" : 0}, 100); 

    });

});​
```

Comment: not sure why this was closed or down voted. the question was presented with a jsfiddle example making it not vauge

Comment: It was downvoted because i had forgotten to post code here on stackoverflow. Im quite a newbie here.

Comment: well the answer worked and for some reason Casper closed it and downvoted it and now I post any questions. how can I fix this?

Comment: You should ask a new question.